# Spring security generates infinite log (and crashes)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Spring MVC web app. When I try to access a `js` or `css` resource liked with a `<c:url/>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value = '/resources/js/global.js' />"></script>
```

and defined as per:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Trying to load a page with Firefox works fine except for the resources part, which ends in an HTTP 500:

```
 Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'resources/js/resources/js....
```

Spring generates an infinite concatenation of `/js/resources/js/resources` to the logger and naturally crashes out of heap space. I tried changing a few things around but there doesn't seem to be any reason for this to break.

EDIT: I discovered the error goes away if I take out the follwing function in a `@Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/**"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}) 
public ModelMap dataForIndex() {
    logger.debug("Executing dataForIndex");
    ModelMap returnModel = new ModelMap();
    returnModel.addAttribute("userName", "John");
    logger.debug("Return from dataForIndex: " + returnModel);

    return returnModel;
}
```

What's the error here?

Comment: A few suggestions. Try to reduce the sample which reproduces the problem - your question says "spring security generates infinite log", but you haven't actually stated whether the problem only happens with security enabled. Have you tried removing it? Is the problem still there? The actual error is after the Spring Security filter chain. You should also clarify how a particular request URL is handled (e.g using curl) ? Finally, you can always use a debugger and step through the code to work out where the dispatch goes awry. All the code is available and you can easily add it to your IDE.

Comment: I managed to scope the problem a bit. It just breaks resource resolution (taking out security doesn't change anything) and if I take out the mvc config it resolves the jsps correctly (not so the resources).

Comment: An error relative to a mapping, also posted above.